# Cannot enable xp_cmdshell on SQL Server 2017 Express on Linux

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to enable the `xp_cmdshell` on SQL Server 2017 Express running on Linux RedHat 7.4

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15), and getting the following error:

> The specified option 'xp_cmdshell' is not supported by this edition of
>   SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure.

Is it missing because `xp_cmdshell` does not work on Linux, or because I'm using the free Express edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And you won't be able to enable it either. [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2017 on Linux - Unsupported features & services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported):

> The following features and services are not available for SQL Server 2017 on Linux. The support of these features will be increasingly enabled over time.
>
> | Area | Unsupported feature or service |
> | --- | --- |
> | **Database engine** | Merge replication |
> |  | Stretch DB |
> |  | PolyBase |
> |  | Distributed query with 3rd-party connections |
> |  | Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server |
> |  | System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.) |
> |  | Filetable, FILESTREAM |
> |  | CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set |
> |  | Buffer Pool Extension |

Note "System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.)" is listed as unsupported.

---

The same is true for [SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported) (note that Polybase has been removed from the unsupported items though):

> The following features and services are not available for SQL Server 2019 on Linux. The support of these features will be increasingly enabled over time.
>
> | Area | Unsupported feature or service |
> | --- | --- |
> | **Database engine** | Merge replication |
> |  | Stretch DB |
> |  | Distributed query with 3rd-party connections |
> |  | Linked Servers to data sources other than SQL Server |
> |  | System extended stored procedures (XP_CMDSHELL, etc.) |
> |  | Filetable, FILESTREAM |
> |  | CLR assemblies with the EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE permission set |
> |  | Buffer Pool Extension |

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!